# Prevent the PyCharm-Debugger from automatically exiting the script after it has been run

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pycharm, breakpoints

Is it possible to stop the PyCharm-Debugger automatically after it has executed the last line of code?

Given the following code

```
# Start of module
x = 0
for i in range(3):
    x += 1
# End of module
```

I would like to check that x is indeed 3 after running the script, by asking for the value of x in the debugger console.

Of course this would be possible by adding a new line with arbitrary content to the code to set another breakpoint beneath the loop, but that's kind of annoying.

Comment: just print x? or just add one extra line with a break point? one extra line isn't going to matter

Comment: Just set the break point on `x += 1` ?

Comment: As another option you can enable *Run with Python Console* option in the Run Configuration you are using to debug your script, this way PyCharm will start Python Console after the script execution where you can inspect the scope.